# Python TypeVar with abstract class implementation

Tags: python, abstract-class, type-variables

I have an abstract class that defines functions that need to be implemented by subclasses

```
P = TypeVar('P', int, List[int])

class Abstract(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def process(self, key: int) -> P:
        pass


class Test(Abstract):
    def __init__(self):
       ...
    
    def process(self, key: int) -> P:
        ...
```

The abstract function `process` can return either a `int` or `List[int]`. When creating instances of `Test` I want to set a specific type for a instance to be either `int` or `List[int]` in its `process` function implementation, something like

```
t1 = Test[int]()
t2 = Test[List[int]]()
```

which when calling `process` would then return the specific type

```
res: int = t1.process(1)  # returns an int
res: List[int] = t2.process(1)  # returns a List[int]
```

How/where would I have to specify the types to accomplish that restriction?

Comment: Somewhat, I can probably piece it together with that